# Instrumentation tests and ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS

Tags: android, testing, android-instrumentation

I have an app that changes system settings.

To get permission to write those settings on 23+ it is not enough to define the WRITE_SETTINGS permission in the manifest and I have to send the user to manually enable this permission like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

It is working fine but I'm running in problems when I try to write instrumentation tests.

If I just run the test as it is, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.my.app.test does not belong to 10504
```

I'm new to android testing and not familiar with all the tools available. What would be the best way to handle this?